# storage double map key deletion

Tags: rust, runtime, storagemap

Consider a substrate double map

```rust
pub Foo get(fn category_by_moderator): double_map
            hasher(blake2_128_concat) T::K1, hasher(blake2_128_concat) T::K2 => T::V;
```

Suppose I want to delete all elements having `k1` as prefix. This is the behavior guaranteed
by `Foo::remove_prefix(k1)`.
Will this result in a `O(1)` time complexity since I am accessing one key only or will it result in a `O(n)` time complexity (with `n` being the all the elements having `k1` as prefix) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This results in `O(n)` time complexity. We need to iterate the storage from the first key starting with `k1` until there are no more elements starting with `k1`.